# What is the difference between these two ways to run a Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

So I am currently writing a Java project for university (we've only started studying Java this semester and it's kind of easier for me since i have studied other object oriented languages), however I do not understand why this needs to be written when you create a new GUI

[image: This invoke later method]

When the Frame/App runs for me without any problems when I type only

[image: this]

The lecturer just goes over things very fast and a lot of things go unexplained which is annoying and while I can find answers to most, this one has been bugging me.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, always copy and paste your code as text. See [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: I see, thank you for the quick answer and apologies for the images.It is my first time asking here, have a good day :)

Comment: No problem, you're welcome :)